# libeay32.dll error when starting RCurl

Tags: windows-7, dll

I am trying to use [RCurl](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/) (from within the R programming language).  And I get the following error:

> The procedure entry point
>   ASN1_const_check_infinite_end could
>   not be located in the dynamic link
>   library libeay32.dll

Before that I had the warning that  libeay32.dll is missing.  I downloaded some copy from online, and put it into the system32 directory - and I ended up with the error above.

I then ran regclean pro ([link](http://www.systweak.com/RegistryCleaner/)) but that didn't help either.

I work on win 7.  Any suggestions how to solve this?

(I wasn't sure if this belongs here on stackoverflow, so I tried both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is caused by using an older DLL that the one needed by RCurl. It means that the Windows library loader couldn't locate in the library a function that RCurl wants to use.

You need a newer version, try downloading it from the OpenSSL official page, current version is 1.0.0b:

http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Note also that you don't need to put int in system32, it's better is you put it in the RCurl directory (MS no longer recommends putting libraries in system folders because of [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell)).

Comment: +1, but edited the answer to point to the _actual_ [official](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) builds of latest version.